# Change smtp name

Tags: smtp, email

My question is probably very easy to answer but I have been struggling with this the whole day. Actually, I would like to change my smtp.mail name and account that is shown as sending the emails in the header. I changed the "From" but it shows only in the "visible" part of the email and there are values that are different in the header.

In this example :

Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce@taggedmail.com designates 67.221.174.127 as permitted sender) client-ip=67.221.174.127;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce@taggedmail.com designates 67.221.174.127 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce@taggedmail.com; dkim=pass (test mode) header.i=tagged@taggedmail.com

smtp.mail=bounce@taggedmail.com
account=bounce

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I really get your problem. I guess you set up a From: address  Yourname@yourdomain.com in your mail client and used a mail server where you are authorized as bounce@taggedmail.com to send the mail. Now you are wondering why this address appears in the headers. Is this correct?

If so: The values in the header are written by the SMTP server (not the client), and may be rewritten by the server to match the user that logged in. You can't change this in your mail client.